# Need Nodes to Appear Only Once

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've created a view to display items with a certain content type. I'd like to display the terms in an associated taxonomy along with them. Many of these nodes have more than one term selected.

The output currently displays nodes one time for each taxonomy term assigned. How can I adjust this so that it displays each node once with every term associated with it?

Thank you!

Comment: are you using term reference field in Drupal 7?

Comment: @ShabirA. I'm have a relationship to the taxonomy I'm using and a "Has Taxonomy Term ID with Depth" Contextual Filter. Whenever I try to add a term field it starts displaying each node more than once for each term.

Comment: use distinct will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply **GROUP BY** or **DISTINCT** by enabling views aggregation settings to remove duplicate records.

1. Go and edit your view
2. In Advanced » OTHER section by enabling Use aggregation: Yes
3. In FIELDS or FILTER CRITERIA section, select and apply Aggregation settings for which fields you want to group by or distinct.

Comment: I discovered that I was sorting based on the TID and not the Entity ID. Changing this solved it. Thank you for your help!